# Include path in vscode not working... File not found

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include-path

I used cpptools extension in vscode.

I used Win32 configuration :

[image]

My c_cpp_properties.json is :

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": ["C:/Program Files (x86)/PICC/Devices"]
        }
    ]
}
```

But , in my code ...

[image]

And in my PICC/Devices folder :

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Please help me :(

Comment: Since you have added the directory to the system search path, try using angle-brackets instead, like `#include <18f452.h>`